# Call function when user selects an option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an radio select field in an form:

```
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :sicherheit, "Verdacht auf" %>
   <%= f.radio_button :sicherheit, 'V' %>
   <%= f.label :sicherheit, "Zustand nach" %>
   <%= f.radio_button :sicherheit, 'Z' %>
   <%= f.label :sicherheit, "Ausschluss" %>
   <%= f.radio_button :sicherheit, "A" %>
   <%= f.label :sicherheit, "Gesicherte Diagnose" %>
   <%= f.radio_button :sicherheit, "G" %>
  </div>
```

I would like that when an users selects one option, the action validate in icd controller is called! To imagine it better, i need something like an, link to:

```
 <%= link_to "#{g.nummer}", icd_validate_path(g), remote: true %>
```

I hope you understand what i want? Thanks!

Comment: so you're saying it needs to validate when they click the radio button or when they submit the form?  if it's validate on click, i think you'll need to use javascript

Comment: When the user clicks on an radio button, and not when the form gets submitted!

Comment: sorry, edited that - i meant if it's validate **on click** you'll need javascript (i think!)

Comment: Yes but how can i call an controller action with jquery?

Comment: sorry, my javascript skills are quite limited - try searching SO for 'rails on click validations using javascript' or similar - also, update your post tags to include javascript.  good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need an AJAX call using Jquery, but make sure `icd_validate_path(g)` is correct and defined in route.rb and your controller responses the js format.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: '<%= icd_validate_path(g) %>', data: {'value': $(this).val()}, success: function(data){
           alert('success'); 
           //do some your actions.
        }})
    });
});
</script>
```